# System(Rscript ) not returning and error but not running either

Tags: r, asynchronous, command, system, rscript

I want to source an asynchronous background processes using System() and Rscript but it doesn't seem to run the script. The line I'm using is below:

system("Rscript -e 'source(\"/Users/Federico/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/taskscheduleR/extdata/PriceTesting.R\")'", wait=FALSE)

In the sourced script I have it write a simple csv and it does not write which leads me to believe its not running the script at all.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rscript already runs the script, so you can simply pass the path to the script as argument:

```
system("Rscript '/Users/colin/R/dslinr/plop.R'")
```

That being said, I have no pblm here running :

```
system("Rscript -e 'source(\"/Users/colin/R/dslinr/plop.R\")'", wait=FALSE)
```

Does the script works if you launch it from the shell? Are you sure your path is correct ? It seems to be mixing unix path (with /User), and win-library (windows library for R).

Comment: path is correct It seems like its not recognizing Rscript as a command

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this and it runs. All I can think of is that maybe Rscript isn't a recognized command.

```
 system("C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/Rscript.exe 
 C:/Users/Federico/Documents/R/win-
 library/3.4/taskscheduleR/extdata/PriceTesting.R", wait=FALSE)
```